# How to use __set__ and __get__ in Python Selenium PageObjects

Tags: python, selenium, getter-setter, getter, setter

I am a beginner in Python and I'm trying to understand Python Selenium's documentation on page objects: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/page-objects.html

What does the **set** and **get** methods do in element.py? And how should we call them and use search_text_element in page.MainPage? Given this file structure, how can I find a search text field in a website, enter a string and send By.RETURN?

Answer (score 0):

You usually won't call these directly. When objects that have these methods are used as attributes in another class (for example, in a class representing a web page), they will be called automatically when the attribute is retrieved (`__get__`) or written with the `=`assignment operator.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply....just a follow-up question...then what's the use of setting up element.py?

Comment: If you are asking about the `__set__`method in the 'element.py' snippet in the linked page, it sends the string passed as if they were typed on the selected page element. i.e. `page.my_element = "abcd"`will behave as if someone typed "abcd" on the web element represented by "my_element" on the "page" python object wich proxies a webpage loaded on the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, Python just gets and sets values on attributes without any special processing just like a basic storage. But if you are implementing [*Page Objects*](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/page-objects.html) where `Base page` *class* is initialized on accessing every page object class, you might need to validate the *Page Object's* value that's was being assigned. You may want to retrieve a value and cache it for later use.

In short, a [descriptor](http://martyalchin.com/2007/nov/23/python-descriptors-part-1-of-2/) is an attribute value that has any of the following methods:

- *`__get__(self, instance, owner)`*: This will be called when the attribute is retrieved (`value = obj.attr`), and whatever it returns is what will be given to the code that requested the attribute’s value.
- *`__set__()`*: This gets called when a value is set to the attribute (`obj.attr = 'value'`), and shouldn’t return anything at all.
- *`__delete__()`*: This is called when the attribute is deleted from an object (`del obj.attr`)

in the descriptor protocol. If any of those methods are defined for an attribute, it is said to be a [descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-descriptor).

---

### [**get**](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/dunderdsc/get.html)

Called to get the attribute of the owner class (class attribute access) or of an instance of that class (instance attribute access). An example:

```
class Ten:
    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
    return 10

class A:
    x = 5                       # Regular class attribute
    y = Ten()                   # Descriptor instance

a = A()             # Make an instance of class A
print(a.x)          # Normal attribute lookup
print(a.y)          # Descriptor lookup
```

Prints:

```
5
10
```

Explanation: In the `a.x` attribute lookup, the dot operator finds `'x': 5` in the class dictionary. In the `a.y` lookup, the dot operator finds a descriptor instance, recognized by its **get** method. Calling that method returns 10. Note that the value 10 is not stored in either the class dictionary or the instance dictionary. Instead, the value 10 is computed on demand.

---

### This usecase

As per the code in [element.py](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/page-objects.html#page-elements)

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait


class BasePageElement(object):
    """Base page class that is initialized on every page object class."""

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
    """Sets the text to the value supplied"""

    driver = obj.driver
    WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_name(self.locator))
    driver.find_element_by_name(self.locator).clear()
    driver.find_element_by_name(self.locator).send_keys(value)

    def __get__(self, obj, owner):
    """Gets the text of the specified object"""

    driver = obj.driver
    WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_name(self.locator))
    element = driver.find_element_by_name(self.locator)
    return element.get_attribute("value")
    
class Pages:

    element = BasePageElement()

    def __init__(self, element, value):
          self.element = element              # Calls __set__()
      self.value = value                  

    
login_page = Pages(username, 'Henry')  # Sets the username field with text Henry
```